# KnockoutJS computed is undefined

Tags: knockout.js

I have a computed observable of two integer based observables that I'm trying to turn into a timespan value. It seems like it should be pretty easy by looking at documentation but I am getting an undefined:undefined value from my computed. Apologies if this is hard to follow. Any help is much appreciated. Here is my JS:

```
var Routine = function (routine_name, minutes, seconds, duration, rest, rounds) {
    this.routine_name = ko.protectedObservable(routine_name);
    this.minutes = ko.protectedObservable(minutes);
    this.seconds = ko.protectedObservable(seconds);
    //this.duration = ko.protectedObservable(duration);
    this.rest = ko.protectedObservable(rest);
    this.rounds = ko.protectedObservable(rounds || 1);

    this.duration = ko.computed(function () {
        return this.minutes + ':' + this.seconds;
    });

} 

var RoutineModel = function (Routines) {

    var self = this;
    self.routine_id = ko.observable();
    self.routine_name = ko.observable();
    //self.duration = ko.observable();
    self.minutes = ko.observable();
    self.seconds = ko.observable();
    self.rest = ko.observable();
    self.rounds = ko.observable();
    self.workout_name = ko.observable();

    self.duration = ko.computed(function () {
        return self.minutes() + ':' + self.seconds();
    });

this.Routines = ko.observableArray(Routines);

this.selectedRoutine = ko.observable();

this.addRoutine = function () {

            var newRoutine = new Routine("new routine", 0, 0, 0, 0);
            self.Routines.push(newRoutine);
            self.selectedRoutine(newRoutine);

    };

this.acceptRoutineEdit = function () {
        var selectedRoutine = self.selectedRoutine();
        selectedRoutine.routine_name.commit();
        selectedRoutine.minutes.commit();
        selectedRoutine.seconds.commit();
        //selectedRoutine.duration.commit();
        selectedRoutine.rest.commit();
        selectedRoutine.rounds.commit();
        self.selectedRoutine(null);

        selectedRoutine.duration = ko.computed(function () {
            return selectedRoutine.minutes + ':' + selectedRoutine.seconds;
        });
    };
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `duration` computed is using `this` and is being calculated with the wrong context.

When you define a `computed`, you can pass in a second argument to control the value of `this` when your computed is evaluated like:

```
   this.duration = ko.computed(function () {
        return this.minutes() + ':' + this.seconds();
    }, this);
```

Your other computeds, don't use `this`, so don't seem to have the same issue.

Additionally, in this computed and in `selectedRoutine.duration` computed, make sure that you call observables as functions to retrieve their value like:

```
return selectedRoutine.minutes() + ':' + selectedRoutine.seconds();
```

Comment: You could also use "var self=this" inside Routine, like you did in RoutineModel and use self instead of this.